# Can connect React Routes in my application it is keeping giving me errors I have tried everything to debug but can figure out the issue

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom, react-dom

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPcWM.png)

I assumed the version would be the cause of the error while using the react route, so I verified it and adjusted my code in accordance with the version, but I still couldn't resolve the issue. I spent much time trying to fix it, but I still can't.

I want to connect the navbar items to other page and also the signup button but non of these are connecting, I tried to upgrade and downgrade the react and react-dom versions, install the hook forms, and try the peer-dependency command, but nothing seemed to work. It shows the error on useRef, but I am not using useRef anywhere; instead, I am using useState.

Comment: The `BrowserRouter` uses the `React.useRef` hook. The error is informing you that `React` is null for some reason. Can you [edit] to share your package.json file and relevant code you are working with? See [mcve].